# Stationary points of a family of functions which converge uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

**Here's the motivation of my question:**

Consider the family of functions $\mathrm{f}_n(x) := \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)$. It is easy to show that $\mathrm{f}_n$ converges uniformly to the zero function.

To prove this, we need to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|\mathrm{f}_n(x) - 0| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n > N$.

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\,\sin(nx)-0\right| = \left|\frac{1}{n}\,\sin(nx)\right|
=\left|\frac{1}{n}\right| \cdot \left|\sin(nx)\right| \le \frac{1}{|n|} \cdot 1=\frac{1}{n}$$

Hence $|\mathrm{f}_n(x) - 0| < \varepsilon$ if $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$ and so $|\mathrm{f}_n(x) - 0| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

This example is used often to show that derivatives are not inherited from uniformly convergent sequences. For example, $\mathrm{f}_n{'}(0) = 1$ or all positive integers $n$, and yet the zero function has derivative zero everywhere.

**Here's my build-up to my question:**

I'm interested in when the derivatives of the limiting functions agree with the limit function.
$$\mathrm{f}_n{'}(x) = \cos(nx)$$
The limit function, i.e. the zero function, has zero derivative everywhere. Let $$D_n := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \mathrm{f}_n{'}(x) = 0 \}$$
For a fixed $n$, we have $\mathrm{f}_n{'}(x) = 0$ if, and only if, 
$$nx \in \left\{\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k : k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$
It would seem to me then that
$$D_n = \left\{ \left(\frac{1+2k}{2n}\right)\!\pi : k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$

**Here's my question:**

What can be said about the set
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} D_n$$

My instinct is that it will be countable and dense in the reals, just like the rationals are.

**EDIT:** For example, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$ can we find an $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for which an element of $D_n$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $x$ for all $n > N$?

Comment: I don't recall saying that it was. I said that the limit function of $\frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)$ was zero. The function $\cos(nx)$ is the derivative, and I don't claim anything about its limit as a function.

Comment: What does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} D_n$ mean, if $D_n$ is a set? Are you defining it to be the set of all $x$ such that there is a sequence $a_n\in D_n$ such that $a_n\rightarrow x$?

Comment: @AlexR. I suppose that this is the heart of my question. What does it mean? For each $n$ we get a set of points. As $n$ increases, these points bunch together, while still carrying on indefinitely. What happens when $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Usually set limits are defined like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you. I've just had a look and very little of it makes any sense. Typical Wikipedia article it seems: written by experts for experts to read.

Comment: For example, the limsup of a sequence of sets is defined to be a collection of elements $x$ which belong to an infinite number of $D_n$. So for example if $x$ is in this limit that means you can find an infinite sequence $i_1,i_2,\cdots$ such that $x\in D_{i_k}$ for every $k$. Can you find any such elements?

Another kind of limit is the liminf, which is a collection of elements $x$ which belong to every single $D_n$ for all $n>N=N(x)$, where i've emphasized that $N$ can depend on $x$. In other words, each $x$ doesn't belong to $D_n$ only for a finite number of $n$.

Comment: @AlexR. Both of these definitions seem to relate to uncountable sets, like intervals. The ideal I have in mind is about discrete sets. For example something like 

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{ k + \frac{1}{n} : k \in \mathbb{N} \right\} = \mathbb{N}$$

This doesn't seem to fit with the lim.sup or lim.inf ideas.

I suppose $D_n \to \{0\}$ as $n \to \infty$ because

$$\lim_{n \to 0} \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{\pi k}{n} \right) = 0$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score -1):

Counterexample: $f_n(x) = x/n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1],$ but $f_n(x)$ has no stationary points.

Comment: A counter example to what? I asked a specific question about a specific example. **Did you read my post?**

Comment: I assumed you were working towards a general proposition. Pardon my abject stupidity.

Comment: Feel free to delete your "answer".

Comment: Nope, gonna leave it as is. By the way, the answer to your question in your EDIT is: Obviously yes.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, I'll have to down-vote it because it isn't helpful. It doesn't address my question.

Comment: It's a very brave thing you do. I congratulate you.